# Converting a List<Dictionary<string,string>> into a single Dictionary<string,string>

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries in C# as below:

```
List<Dictionary<string, string>> dict
```

Where:

```
dict[0] = { "key": "Name", "value" : "test1" }
```

And:

```
dict[1] = { "key": "ID", "value" : "100" }
```

Now, I want my resulting `Dictionary` to contain:

```
Dictionary<string, string> reultDict = { "Name": "test1", "ID" : "100" }
```

Comment: try this `var result = dict.ToDictionary(d => d.Values.First());`

Comment: This didn't worked.

Comment: I am afraid `dict[0] = { "key": "Name", "value" : "test1" }` is not valid C# code. It throws an invalid syntax error. Can you post the actual code please.

Comment: Can the two dictionaries contain an item with the same key? If so, can the value for that key be different in the two dictionaries?

Comment: I mean, dict[0] will have two key value pairs like { "key": "Name"} and {"value" : "test1"}. Simillarly, dict[1] will have {"key": "ID"} and { "value" : "100"}

Comment: Can the two dictionaries contain an item with the same key? If so, can the value for that key be different in the two dictionaries? - No it will always be unique

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use LINQ:

```
var result = dict.SelectMany(c => c).ToDictionary(c => c.Key, c => c.Value);
```

Test the working code here:

```
List<Dictionary<string, string>> dict = new List<Dictionary<string, string>>()
{ 
    new Dictionary<string, string>(), new Dictionary<string, string>()
};

dict[0].Add("Name", "test1");
dict[1].Add("ID", "100");

var result = dict.SelectMany(c => c).ToDictionary(c => c.Key, c => c.Value);
```

Also here is another solution suggested by @Jason which seems to be more close to what the OP is looking for:

```
dict.Select(c => new KeyValuePair<string, string>(c["key"], c["value"])
```

Or

```
dict.ToDictionary(d => d["key"], d => d["value"])
```

Comment: It's nearly there. Instead of this: `dict.SelectMany(c => c)`, you want something like `dict.Select(c => new KeyValuePair<string, string>(c["key"], c["value"])`. Or just `dict.ToDictionary(d => d["key"], d => d["value"])`

Comment: If there is any chance there will be dictionaries that share a key, this will not work. Try your code with `dict[0].Add("Name", "test1")` and `dict[1].Add("Name", "100");` and it'll throw because of the duplicate `Name` key.